# How to update USNs without upgrading versions?

Tags: 16.04, package-management, security

I want to update few packages which are listed in [USNs for 16.04](https://usn.ubuntu.com/releases/ubuntu-16.04-lts/) any package I want to update takes me to launchpad page and there the update is available in .tar.xz format along with the original version but I am not able to find a way to install those updates, there are no make files in them, no install options in them, I tried to check if .tar.xz files can be updated directly for the package but all I find is how to unzip the files.

I don't want to use `apt-get upgrade`  that can mess with versions in server

I tried `unattended-upgrade/s` that didn't updated any thing.

How to apply those updates listed in USN without messing with versions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The Ubuntu Security Team already did the work for you.**

The Security Team patches only the vulnerability in the CVE/USN. They do not upgrade anything else. They do not patch non-security bugs. They do not increment the upstream version to fix a vuln.

The patched packages are uploaded to the -security pocket. For 16.04, that's xenial-security. Simply enable that repository in your Software & Upgrades control panel (or /etc/apt.sources.list)

Version numbers: If the original package version is something like "Foo 3.2.4", then the new upload from the Ubuntu Security Team will be something like "Foo 3.2.4~Ubuntu0", so that apt will interpret the change as an upgrade and pull in the new package.

For more information on how that Ubuntu Security Team works, check out the [Ubuntu Security Team Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam). The [Ubuntu Security Podcast](https://ubuntusecuritypodcast.org/) can also be a handy learning tool.